# How to debug PHP code in a file with a different file extension

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I have project, which has files with `.php.t` extension. There may be a *PHP* code and code, specific to the project core.

- `php.ini` has all configuration that needed.
- *PhpStorm* is fully configured and works.
- `.php.t` is associated with *PHP*

If I set a breakpoint in a `.php` file and launch debugging project as "PHP Web Page" - debug session is starting successfully. But if I set a breakpoint in a `.php.t` file and launch debugging project as "PHP Web Page"  - nothing happens. If run debugging the file as  "PHP Script" - it works. But it is no sense for me, because there's a lot of dependencies in file, which must be include to file.

What and Where I have to write or set up to debug `.php.t` files? Which way to dig?

- System: Ubuntu 18.04
- PHP: 7.2
- Full info about PhpStorm:

  ```
  PhpStorm 2018.3
  Build #PS-183.4284.150, built on November 21, 2018
  Licensed to lb od
  Subscription is active until July 30, 2019
  JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b15 amd64
  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
  Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
  ```

Comment: .php.t sounds like some templating engine. Do you use any?

Comment: @Tom it is something like template, yes. But it may contain even just php classes)) It's the odd kinda framework, written by a developer in a company. These `.php.t`  files may contain html, php, framework's syntax and everything you can imagine. That's sad... Nevertheless, despite *templating*, it can be debugging as a script.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by " launch debugging project as "PHP Web Page" - nothing happens"? IDE should open a corresponding page in a browser: is it opens? Does it load nothing? Or it just loads the page without stopping at breakpoints?

Comment: @Ástþór "nothing happens" ==  it loads the page without stopping at breakpoints

Comment: Probably caused by that custom framework-specific code. You can check XDebug logs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs and also IDE logs. You can also contact support via Help > Contact Support to have this looked into

Comment: @SergeyMishin What's your Xdebug version? Get it from `phpinfo()` captured via browser (as you may have different php.ini used by CLI and Apache). Extension should not matter here as long as in IDE it's associated with "PHP File" type (assuming that form php/web server side is all setup correctly as well).

Comment: @LazyOne Xdebug v2.6.0. `/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` and `/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` refers to the same file (xdebug.ini) inside `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/` folder

Comment: @SergeyMishin Thanks (as you need PhpStorm 2018.3 or newer for Xdebug 2.7.x). Maybe it's a code then? I mean -- file meant to be included but not executed directly? Will it work if you create another file with such extension and put a very simple code like `<?php $a = 1; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b, echo $c;` -- all on separate lines? What Xdebug log has to say about such debug session? If I create a file with such extension and configure my IIS to process such files as PHP .. it works fine here (v2019.1 though; Windows 10).

Comment: @LazyOne `file meant to be included but not executed directly?` --- yes. `Maybe it's a code then?` --- code is fine)) it works, just cannot be debugged. As I meant in the question body - debugging as "PHP Script" - works, but it's not what I need, 'cause there's many files loaded with __autoload or something similar...Debug log is writing lot of notices: `Undefined index/offset: XXX in YYY`. I thought I should set mapping, but it doesn't work either. Well, as  Ástþór mentioned, I think it's all because of  custom framework-specific code. Or wrong mapping.

Comment: @SergeyMishin Are you trying to debug (better say "launch") that file directly? Or some index.php file .. that will eventually load and execute that code? I say just use zero-config Debugging approach (set IDE to listen to any incoming debug request, navigate to the page that will be executed before needed one, set xdebug cookies (xdebug browser extensions or bookmarklet) and then just run the page. That's how I do --- I do not create individual Run/Debug configs for web pages (only for individual CLI scripts, if I really need it).

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html , this one in particular: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html. If it's still not then ... then it must be something specific to your framework/code (it's hard to say without having an overall picture of your setup in my head).

Comment: @LazyOne `Are you trying to debug (better say "launch") that file directly? Or some index.php file` - the second one. `use zero-config Debugging approach`- today I've tried all I could try from all jetbrains help  infos: zero-config approach, mapping, ide debug configuration, all in one))  `it's hard to say without having an overall picture of your setup in my head` - I understand, unfortunately I have nothing more to say. Just thanks for helping)

Comment: @SergeyMishin 1) Try placing `xdebug_break();` there (programmatic breakpoint) and see if it will make any diff. 2) Enable and then check xdebug log -- it will tell where breakpoints are set, what file gets debugged etc -- may give you some hints.